# Edit text is getting hide after clicking below to its max line in order to re-type something

Tags: android, android-edittext

I getting very strange problem in my code , as my edit text is working fine for single line comment or multiple line comments but if i enter break lines in my edit text and press back button and then again try to re-type the text on edit text my edit text got hide behind soft key board. I am really not getting its cause.Can any body help me out from this problem.

Here is my code (i am taking about et_comment edit text) :-

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_title_ticket_detail"
            style="@style/TextAppearance"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@color/light_green"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Mukul"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_title_ticket_detail"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    style="@style/TextAppearanceSmallMediumList"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".4"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="@string/category_ticket_details"
                    android:textColor="@color/actionbar_blue" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_category"
                    style="@style/TextAppearanceSmallMediumList"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".6"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    style="@style/TextAppearanceSmallMediumList"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".4"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="@string/priority_ticket_details"
                    android:textColor="@color/actionbar_blue" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_priority"
                    style="@style/TextAppearanceSmallMediumList"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".6"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    style="@style/TextAppearanceSmallMediumList"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".4"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="@string/ticket_no_ticket_details"
                    android:textColor="@color/actionbar_blue" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_ticket_no"
                    style="@style/TextAppearanceSmallMediumList"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".6"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    style="@style/TextAppearanceSmallMediumList"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".4"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="@string/apt_ticket_details"
                    android:textColor="@color/actionbar_blue" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_apt"
                    style="@style/TextAppearanceSmallMediumList"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".6"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    style="@style/TextAppearanceSmallMediumList"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".4"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="@string/created_ticket_details"
                    android:textColor="@color/actionbar_blue" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_created_date"
                    style="@style/TextAppearanceSmallMediumList"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".6"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tt"
            style="@style/TextAppearance"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ll"
            android:background="@color/grey"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="@string/comment_ticket_details"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lv_msg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/ll_msg"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tt"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:stackFromBottom="true"
            android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll" >
        </ListView>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_msg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_msgg"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:maxHeight="2000dp"
                android:minHeight="50dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_comment"
                    style="@style/TextAppearance"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/iv_send"
                    android:background="@drawable/border_grey"
                    android:gravity="top|left"
                    android:hint="@string/enter_msg"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                    android:isScrollContainer="true"
                    android:maxLines="5"
                    android:maxLength="200"
                    android:minHeight="50dp"
                    android:padding="2dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/actionbar_blue"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/actionbar_blue" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_send"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/et_comment"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:background="@color/actionbar_blue"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                    android:maxHeight="100dp"
                    android:minHeight="50dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/send_icon" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_container_image_upload_icon"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/ll_msgg"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                    android:src="@drawable/upload_symbol" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_upload_pic"
                    style="@style/TextAppearanceSmallMediumList"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="@string/upload_pic"
                    android:textColor="@color/actionbar_blue" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_container_fragment_ticket_screen"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/ll_container_image_upload_icon"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:visibility="invisible" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_upload_pic_path"
                    style="@style/TextAppearanceSmallMediumList"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_weight=".9"
                    android:ellipsize="marquee"
                    android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                    android:padding="2dp"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                    android:singleLine="true" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_cross_fragment_ticket_details"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_weight=".1"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/cross" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

and In Android Manifest I declare :-

```html
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustUnspecified"
```

I even try with  adjustpan and adjustResize.

Here is the video link of my problem , please have a look :-

https://www.dropbox.com/s/9284p2e45vo4lyi/VID_20150818_184510215.mp4?dl=0

Any help will be appreciated
Thanks.